# How to track the very first time a controller is called in a user session (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, usersession

I would like to check if a controller is being called for the very first time in the user's session. Is a class variable the right choice for this? Any good practice as to how to implement this check?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `session` variable that sets info in user session. For instance:

```
if session[:my_controller_accessed]
  do_stuff_for_another_visit
else
  session[:my_controller_accessed] = true
  do_stuff_for_first_visit
end
```

More on sessions: https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in your question:
In a user session

You can do smth like this in your controller

```
before_action :record_visit

# ...


def record_visit
  session[:visited_controllets] ||= {}
  session[:visited_controllets][self.class.name] = true
end
```

Later you can check whether the given controller was accessed using `session[:visited_controllets][contoller_class_name]`

Comment: Does this mean `record_visit` would be called before any function in the controller gets called?

Comment: @Biju correct.
Here's the documentation https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters